# Input() keeps skipping the actual input

Tags: python, input

I am trying to get a few inputs in Python and for some reason. I have code like this .

```
input("foo")

x = print("bar")
```

The console skips the input and goes straight to **x**. Well, it does not actually skip input, it just leaves it blank.

How do i ensure i get the input ?

Comment: Don't you want `x=input('foo')` followed by `print(x)`?

Comment: “*it just leaves it blank.*” *What* leaves *what* blank? Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Are you running this from a file or typing it directly into Python.  If the latter, then the blank line you typed was the input.

Comment: Understand how input works here - https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input. It returns the read value. The string you pass as the argument is an optional prompt which it simply prints.

Comment: So, Frank may have the answer. I am not actually running the file. I am typing straight into the console. Still i do believe with other languages that would not be a problem, i may be wrong though.

Comment: I don't think the variable name makes a difference. i am not trying to print the variable. The print was arbitrary, it's to say that skip a few lines and input() jumps to what ever line of code is next. Instead of taking actual user Input.

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax:

```
x = input("foo")
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is:

```
name = input("Your name: ")
print(name)
```

Comment: `in` is not a good variable name ...

Comment: For some reason i can't run a Python file on my IDE.

Comment: you shouldn't name a variable after a keyword as @JoranBeasley suggested ....